# Retrieving ids of chid divs using jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Please have a look on the code below ..

```
                <div id="click_me">Save</div> 


<div id="blocks_sortable">
    <div id="block_1">
        <h2>Block 1</h2>

        <div class="items_sortable connectedSortable">
            <div id="item_1"> 
                <span>Item 1</span></div>   
            <div id="item_2"> 
                <span>Item 2</span></div>
            <div id="item_3"> 
                <span>Item 3</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="block_2">
        <h2>Block 2</h2>

        <div class="items_sortable connectedSortable">
            <div id="item_4"> 
                <span>Item 4</span></div>   
            <div id="item_5"> 
                <span>Item 5</span></div>
            <div id="item_6"> 
                <span>Item 6</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#click_me").click(function() {
            var result = $("#blocks_sortable > div");

            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                var str = ""; 
                var str2 = "";
                var block = result[i]; //div object

                //retrieve block id and create the string with id
                str += "block="+$(block).attr("id")+"&items=";

                //trying to select all the items of the current Block
                var result2 = $(block+" > div");                        
                    for(var j=0; j<result2.length; j++){
                        var item = result2[j];

                        str2 += $(item).attr("id")+",";
                    } //end for items

                str = str+str2;
                // looking for a final string in the format of .. block=block_1&items=item_1,item_2,item_3 for loop 1
                alert(str);
            }
    });
</script>
```

It is not working. Is there any easier and working solution to get these ids. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check firebug for any javascript errors?

Comment: hmm.. got this Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement]' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x8057001e (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_STRING)" location: "<unknown>" data: no] ...

Comment: Check out my answer below about the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function is your friend

```
$.map( 
    $("#blocks_sortable > div"),
    function(elementOfArray){
        var block = $(elementOfArray);
        var children = $.map(
            $("div[id]", block),
            function( eoa ){
                return eoa.id;
            }).join(",");

        return elementOfArray.id + "=" + children;
    }
).join(",");
```

Will return `"block_1=item_1,item_2,item_3,block_2=item_4,item_5,item_6"`, which gets you much closer to where you're going (I think).

**EDIT:** [Solution](http://jsbin.com/ofopi3/) and [source](http://jsbin.com/ofopi3/edit) here.

Comment: Great .. I like your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting an error when you call  `str += "block="+$(block).attr("id")+"&items=";`

.attr is not working because block is a dom element and not a jquery object.  You are having the same issues with var item too.

The working solution is [here](http://jsbin.com/itexo/edit).  And the demo is [here](http://jsbin.com/itexo).

This javascript fixes it:

```
   $("#click_me").click(function() {
            var result = $("#blocks_sortable > div");

            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                var str = "";
                var str2 = "";
                var block = result[i]; //div object

                //retrieve block id and create the string with id
                str += "block="+ block.id +"&items=";

                //trying to select all the items of the current Block
                var result2 = $("#" + block.id + "> div > div");
                    for(var j=0; j<result2.length; j++){
                        var item = result2[j];

                        str2 += item.id +",";
                    } //end for items

                str = str+str2;
                // looking for a final string in the format of .. block=block_1&items=item_1,item_2,item_3 for loop 1
                alert(str);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Adding links for working solution, very nice.  I will blatantly copy you sir!

Comment: @Jon +1 .. you r great .. it works .. but I have accepted @ROMANARMY solution as its easier me to achieve what i want to do that way.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, Thanks for adding your solution as well, and it would be great if you could put a demo up.  I've learned something new for sure!  @user187580, I'm glad you found your solution!  That's what we're here for, I'm going to give  R0MANARMY +1 on his solution too, I agree it's better, and very cool :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#click_me").click(function() {
        var result = $("#blocks_sortable > div"); 

        for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
            var str = ""; 
            var str2 = "";
            var block = result[i].id; //div object

            //retrieve block id and create the string with id
            //str += "block="+$(block).attr("id")+"&items=";
            str += "block="+ block + "&";
            //trying to select all the items of the current Block
            var inner_span = "#" + block + " > div";
            var result2 = $(inner_span).children();

                for(var j=0; j<result2.length; j++){
                    var item = result2[j];

                    str2 += $(item).attr("id")+",";
                } //end for items

            str = str+str2;
            // looking for a final string in the format of .. block=block_1&items=item_1,item_2,item_3 for loop 1
            alert(str); // output block=block_1&item_1,item_2,item_3 
                        //        block=block_2&item_4,item_5,item_6

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

try without ">"

```
var result = $("#blocks_sortable div");
```

Comment: That will also select the **<div class="items_sortable connectedSortable">** div giving him an element without an ID.