# Replace Div content with jQuery/AJAX - with button ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm building a website that is like a "choose your own adventure" type game. On the page there will be a question with three different choices (as buttons) for the user. When they click on the button jQuery and AJAX will replace the question text with a new question from a separate HTML file. All of the buttons will be replaced as well and will be written up in that separate HTML file.

My problem is that I need a way to have each button have their own ID number so that when jQuery gets the request to change the question it goes to a specific file with a new question that matches the ID number on the button. So each button will have an ID that corresponds to the new question.

**In short:** Is there a way to retrieve an ID or data attribute from a clicked button, and pass that information into my jQuery/AJAX function? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving ids of chid divs using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599971/retrieving-ids-of-chid-divs-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a way to retrieve an ID or data attribute from a clicked button, and pass that information into my jQuery/AJAX function?"

There are a few ways you can do this. Here is one of the easiest ways:

```
<div class="button" id="button1">Click Me</div>

var clicked = '';

$('.button').click(function() {
    clicked = $(this).attr('id');
    window.alert('You clicked: '+clicked);
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5vok1gs/) to demonstrate.

Comment: The script runs perfectly the first time when replacing the content from the homepage, but when I try and replace that content again with another button nothing happens. Any idea why it will not replace the content a second time?

Comment: If you still haven't figured this out, post a new question with your most recent code and post a link to the new question here to notify me.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding onto the above answer. If you have the HTML file names the same as the button ID you can add it directly to your AJAX request.

```
<div class="button" id="button1">Click Me</div>

$('.button').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this).attr('id'),
    url = 'includes/' + $this + '.html';   // Select file url
    $.post(url, function(data) {           
        $('#target_div').html(data).show();    // Display external file to target div 
    });
});
```